# Are there any word start with 'a' and means 'iterate'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am in a startup and we are planning to make a product.
We need an eye-catchy presentation of our solution.

And we want a word which means `iterate`, or `upgrade spirally`,
and it should start with `a`.

Are there any words meet the needs described above?

**UPDATE**： when I say `upgrade spirally`, what I want to express is
to upgrade our product quickly and repeatedly by collect feedback information of our customers.

I am not a native english speaker, sorry for the misunderstand.

Comment: *Ascend*? *Advance*? *Accentuate*? I have no idea what *upgrade* ***spirally*** could possibly mean.

Comment: @JasonBassford I have updated the question.

Comment: ***Agile*** doesn’t mean *iterate* but your development cycle might be described as “agile”.  And it starts with an ‘A’.

Comment: Arbitrary letter arrangement in a  word is a better fit with Puzzling.SE.

Comment: To spiral means to keep increasing, so maybe *accelerate*?

Comment: *aggregating* or *assimilating* feedback to advance your product...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Accumulate** fits the description

From [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accumulate):

> Definition of accumulate
>
> *transitive verb*
>
> : to gather or pile up especially little by little : AMASS
> // *accumulate a fortune*
>
> *intransitive verb*
>
> : to increase gradually in quantity or number
> // *snow accumulating to a depth of several feet*

Comment: How would you use *accumulate* in a sentence in the context the OP asked about? I guess you could say that the product is accumulating features, but what if the product in question is just going through development iterations that improve its existing features or ease of use without adding new features?

Comment: We think the words `ascend` and `accumulate` best fits our condition. And we are talking on this.  Thanks for all .

Answer (score 0):

Jason’s “advance” may be the best single word. Could you combine it alliteratively in a phrase such as “Always Advance”?

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use some sort of variation on "acquisition" or "acquire". With a capital Q, the Q could be a spiral.

Bear in mind that most cool inspirational words and names starting with "A" will already have been registered by software companies as trademarks. That's why there are so many A... companies and products with made-up names that don't mean anything, or deliberately mispelled variations on real words.

(Back in the 90's, I nearly started a business under the name "Amazon", which might have been interesting)

Comment: haha, wonder what is your story